# How to disable margin collapse between sibling elements

Tags: css, margin

Probably this is very stupid and well-known trick, but I haven't found any fix yet. I've tried "`overflow`", "`content: ' '; display: table;`", `padding` and `1px` `border`. No success. So I've made small example to this problem.

There are 2 block elements: header with bottom margin and footer with top margin. The task is to make margins add together: 50 + 49 = 99 px!

```css
.main-header {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.main-footer {
  margin-top: 49px;
}
```

```html
<h1>if distance btw H.&amp;F. is 99 px then margins don't collapse! Unfortunatelly, is is</h1>

<header class="main-header">
  HEADER Lorem ipsum dolor.
</header>

<footer class="main-footer">
  FOOTER <span>&copy;2015 Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use **Flexbox** because it doesn't have `collapsing margins`.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-header {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.main-footer {
  margin-top: 49px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <header class="main-header">
    HEADER Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </header>

  <footer class="main-footer">
    FOOTER <span>&copy;2015 Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 because I was using flexbox *expecting* collapsing margins and starting pulling my hair out because they wouldn't collapse.  Can you cite in the spec where it says that they won't collapse?

Comment: To add to this, put `align-items: flex-start` on `.content` so your elements don't stretch. Their default is to not stretch.

Answer (score 1):

To start, the [flexbox solution that @Nenad Vracar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35257170/128165) posted is the most valid one.

---

**A couple of alternatives**
Assuming the problem is that you do not know if there is something between the two tags you could use an extra selector for this case (*although it would fail if only text is between the two tags as it would still apply the 99 margin*)

```css
.main-header + .main-footer{margin-top:99px;}
```

```html
<h1>if distance btw H.&amp;F. is 99 px then margins don't collapse! Unfortunatelly, is is</h1>

<header class="main-header">
    HEADER Lorem ipsum dolor.
</header>

<footer class="main-footer">
    FOOTER <span>&copy;2015 Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
</footer>
```

---

Now, depending on your situation you could use the tricks you mention and pass the margin to the pseudo-elements.

```css
.main-header:after {
    content: '';
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: table;
}

.main-footer:before {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    margin-top: 49px;
}

.main-header,
.main-footer {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>if distance btw H.&amp;F. is 99 px then margins don't collapse! Unfortunatelly, is is</h1>

<header class="main-header">
    HEADER Lorem ipsum dolor.
</header>

<footer class="main-footer">
    FOOTER <span>&copy;2015 Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can float them to disable the collapsing margins, with `width:100%` to make them to occupy the entire width, rather than determined by the content.

```css
.main-header,
.main-footer {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-header {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.main-footer {
  margin-top: 49px;
}
```

```html
<h1>if distance btw H.&amp;F. is 99 px then margins don't collapse! Unfortunatelly, is is</h1>

<header class="main-header">
  HEADER Lorem ipsum dolor.
</header>

<footer class="main-footer">
  FOOTER <span>&copy;2015 Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

As there's [adjacent siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) and since the margin collapse takes the higher margin, we make use of the **`+`** CSS operator so that when there's no other elements between `header` and `footer`, we increase the `margin-top` of the `footer` to **`99px`**

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/qwn65wwm/)

```css
.main-header {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.main-footer {
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-top: 49px;
}
.main-header + .main-footer {
  /* only when there's no other elements between header and footer this will be applied */
  margin-top: 99px;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">HEADER Lorem ipsum dolor.</header>

<footer class="main-footer">FOOTER <span>&copy;2015 Lorem ipsum dolor.</span></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a simple `float` and `clear:both`, use `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements.

As per MDN:

> Margin collapsing occurs in three basic cases:
>
> **Adjacent siblings**
>   The margins of adjacent siblings are collapsed (except when the later sibling needs to be cleared past floats).

```css
.main-header::after, .main-footer::before {
  content:'';
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  clear:both;
}

.main-header::after {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.main-footer::before {
  margin-top: 49px;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  HEADER Lorem ipsum dolor.
</header>

<footer class="main-footer">
  FOOTER <span>&copy;2015 Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
</footer>
```