# How fill space between margin-collapsed siblings?

Tags: html, css

**Question 1:** Is there any way of automatically having an element fill the space between two margin-collapsed siblings, without adding to the space between the two?

**Question 2:** If not, is there any way of knowing the actual (after margin collapsing) space between two elements when margins are collapsed?

**Background:** I have a page with a vertical list of items. These items have different vertical spacing (i.e. margin)s depending on their content -- i.e. an image item has top and bottom margin of `100px`, a text item has `50px` vertical margin. In order to have good vertical rhythm, margin collapsing is used intentionally.

Now, I need "filler" elements that each take up all the vertical space *between* each item. For example, between an image item and text item, the "filler" would need to be `100px` tall to fill the margin-collapsed space between the two items. Here's an example, with the pink filler filling all the space:
[image]

**Problem:** The list of items is dynamic, so I don't know ahead of time how much space will be in between the items. Because the margins collapse, I can't know ahead of time how tall to make the filler element. I am hoping to avoid having to spell out filler height based on every permutation of item combinations, each with its own value of the spacing between the two item types.

I can't have the filler element affect the space between the two elements (so it's `position: absolute`). Since it's `position: absolute`, I don't see a way of anchoring it to both the item above it and below (only to one of them).

Here is an example of manually setting the height for the filler to fill the space: https://jsfiddle.net/41pgv63s/

Is there any other way of being able to fill the space between two elements that are margin-collapsed, without increasing the space between them? I'd like to not have to manually look at the previous/next item and calculate the filler's height based on that. I'm hoping against hope that there's a CSS-only way to fill the space between the two items, so I don't need to know the context between every neighboring item in the list before setting the height of the filler item.

Comment: And also [How to disable margin collapse between sibling elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257018/how-to-disable-margin-collapse-between-sibling-elements)

Comment: @ObsidianAge as far as I understand OP doesn't want to disable collapse.

Comment: Do you mean;  for example, you have an `<img/>` in a `<p>` tag and your image tag and text are mingled and you want to fill the space between text in the `<p>` tag and the `<img/>`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I don't want to disable margin collapsing.

Comment: @pegasuspect image and paragraph are in separate containers, so they don't mingle.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this, but the quickest came to my mind was this:

```css
.in-between-dweller {
  background-color: rgba(255,128,255, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  background-color: #FAFFBB;
}

.one {  
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.two {  
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.in-between-dweller {
  background-color: rgba(255,128,255, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box one">Box One (margin-bottom: 50px)</div>
  <div class="in-between-dweller">I'm supposed to cover all the space between the two boxes...</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box two">Box Two (margin-top: 100px)</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Unfortunately, in this solution the filler is the same height of box one, instead of the same height as the gap between boxes (if I increase height of box one, the filler grows too).

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I added this solution without deeply investigating your question. After posting this I realized what you want to do, and honestly I would try to avoid using margin collapsing and show all the elements (p, img, div, etc) in the same parent.

Comment: Because what you need is to determine 2 collapsing elements, find the maximum of the margins of the two, and then use that max margin for the height and positioning of the filler element. That is only possible with javascript, as far as I know!