# Keeping divs aligned vertically, and their content from overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have the divs aligned how I want, but the content in the middle div is overlapped by the content of the footer div. Any suggestions on how to get the content in the middle div to increase in height so that it won't overlap the div underneath it?

When divs are aligned vertically, is there anyway to permanently prevent them from overlapping or underlapping the divs above and below them?

I am designing this for a very small screen (Galaxy Fold), and I plan to scale things up as the process continues.

```css
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; /* styles the font of the entire page */
        margin: 0px; /* removes the margin from around the page */
        text-transform: capitalize; /* capitalizes the text on the page */
    }

    li {
        display: inline; /* makes the links lay horizontally */
        list-style-type: none; /* removes the markers for the list items behind the links */
    }

    #nav, #main, #footer {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute; /* fixes the <div> elements to the page */
    }
    
    #nav {
        background-color: #393e46;
        padding-bottom: 16px; /* adds extra padding underneath the search bar */
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }

    #nav-container {
        margin: 0 auto; /* centers the 'nav-container' within the <nav> */
        max-width: 200px;
    }

    #rowA {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .nav-menu {
        margin-top: 0px; /* removes the extra margin above the links in the nav */
    }

    #rowB {
        background-color: green;
    }

    #nav-logo {
        font-size: 32px;
        text-align: center; /* centers the 'FGCPEDIA' logo */
    }

    #rowC {background-color: pink;}

    .nav-menu {
        float: right; /* makes the 'Sign Up/ Log In' links float to the right */
    }
    
    /* removes the highlight from the form when selected */
    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }

    #main {
        background-color: orange;
        top: 26.4%; /* pushes the main directly under the nav */
        /* top: 32.9%; */
    }

    #main-container {
        margin: 0 auto; /* centers the elements in the main */
        max-width: 100px;
    }

    #footer {
        background-color: #222831;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }

    #footer-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 200px;
    }

    .footer-row {
        padding-inline-start: 0px; /* removes the extra padding on the left side of links */
    }

    #copyright {
        color:#eeeeee; /* colors the footer text */
        font-size: 13px; /* the font size of the copyright text is '13' */
        text-align: center; /* centers the  */
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title></title>
            <!-- <link href="../../css/stylesheet2.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
            <link href="stylesheet2.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        
        <body>

            <nav id="nav">
                <div id="nav-container">

                    <!-- nav-row-1 -->
                    <div id="rowA">
                        <ul class="nav-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Sign Up</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">Log In</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <!-- nav-row-1 -->
                    <div id="rowB">
                        <h3 id="nav-logo">DICTIONARY</h3>
                    </div>

                    <!-- nav-row-1 -->
                    <div id="rowC">
                        <form action="" method="get">
                            <input id="nav-search-bar" type="search" placeholder="Search">
                        </form>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </nav>


            <!-- main section -->
            <main id="main">
                <div id="main-container">

                    <!-- header -->
                    <div id="btd-masthead">
                        <h2>Browse the Dictionary</h2>
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <!-- btd links -->
                    <div id="btd-links">
                        
                        <div id="btd-links-1">
                            <a href="a.html">a</a>
                            <a href="b.html">b</a>
                            <a href="c.html">c</a>
                            <a href="d.html">d</a>
                            <a href="e.html">e</a>
                            <a href="f.html">f</a>
                            <a href="g.html">g</a>
                            <a href="h.html">h</a>
                            <a href="i.html">i</a>
                            <a href="j.html">j</a>
                            <a href="k.html">k</a>
                            <a href="l.html">l</a>
                            <a href="m.html">m</a>
                            <a href="n.html">n</a>
                            <a href="o.html">o</a>
                            <a href="p.html">p</a>
                            <a href="q.html">q</a>
                            <a href="r.html">r</a>
                            <a href="s.html">s</a>
                            <a href="t.html">t</a>
                            <a href="u.html">u</a>
                            <a href="v.html">v</a>
                            <a href="w.html">w</a>
                            <a href="x.html">x</a>
                            <a href="y.html">y</a>
                            <a href="z.html">z</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- terms list row -->
                    <div id="terms-container">

                        <!-- column 1 -->
                        <div class="terms-col">

                            <a href="">Abare</a>
                            <a href="../terms/a/adaptation.html">Adaptation</a>
                            <a href="../terms/a/air_dash.html">Air Dash</a>
                            <a href="">Air Throw</a>
                            <a href="../terms/a/air_to_air.html">Air-to-Air</a>
                            <a href="../terms/a/anti_air.html">Anti-Air</a>
                            <a href="../terms/a/armor.html">Armor</a>
                            <a href="">Assist</a>
                            <a href="../terms/a/auto_correct.html">Auto Correct</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>

            <!-- the footer stays the same on every page -->
            <footer id="footer">
                <div id="footer-container">

                    <!-- row 1 -->
                    <ul class="footer-row">
                        <li>
                            <a href="a.html" style="text-transform: none;">Browse the Dictionary:</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="a.html">a</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="b.html">b</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="c.html">c</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="d.html">d</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="e.html">e</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="f.html">f</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="g.html">g</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="h.html">h</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="i.html">i</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="j.html">j</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="k.html">k</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="l.html">l</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="m.html">m</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="n.html">n</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="o.html">o</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="p.html">p</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="q.html">q</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="r.html">r</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="s.html">s</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="t.html">t</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="u.html">u</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="v.html">v</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="w.html">w</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="x.html">x</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="y.html">y</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="z.html">z</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- row 2 -->
                    <ul class="footer-row">
                        <li>
                            <a href="../../index.html">home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="../about_us.html">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="../contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="../disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- row 3 -->
                    <div class="footer-row">
                        <p id="copyright">&copy; 2020 copyright</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>

            <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is that you want your webpage/website to be responsive then use **Viewport Units** like `vw` for **width** and `vh` for **height** instead of `px` and `%` because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive.

Try it, it will surely solve your issue but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to assist you.

I have also converted your CSS file into **Viewport Units** so that it is easier for you to understand it.

```css
body {
        font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; /* styles the font of the entire page */
        margin: 0; /* removes the margin from around the page */
        text-transform: capitalize; /* capitalizes the text on the page */
    }

    li {
        display: inline; /* makes the links lay horizontally */
        list-style-type: none; /* removes the markers for the list items behind the links */
    }

    #nav, #main, #footer {
        width: 100vw;
        position: absolute; /* fixes the <div> elements to the page */
    }
    
    #nav {
        background-color: #393e46;
        padding-bottom: 2.435vw; /* adds extra padding underneath the search bar */
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    #nav-container {
        margin: 0 auto; /* centers the 'nav-container' within the <nav> */
        max-width: 14.641vw;
    }

    #rowA {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .nav-menu {
        margin-top: 0; /* removes the extra margin above the links in the nav */
    }

    #rowB {
        background-color: green;
    }

    #nav-logo {
        font-size: 2.342vw;
        text-align: center; /* centers the 'FGCPEDIA' logo */
    }

    #rowC {background-color: pink;}

    .nav-menu {
        float: right; /* makes the 'Sign Up/ Log In' links float to the right */
    }
    
    /* removes the highlight from the form when selected */
    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }

    #main {
        background-color: orange;
        top: 26.4vh; /* pushes the main directly under the nav */
        /* top: 32.9%; */
    }

    #main-container {
        margin: 0 auto; /* centers the elements in the main */
        max-width: 100vw;
    }

    #footer {
        background-color: #222831;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    #footer-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 14.641vw;
    }

    .footer-row {
        padding-inline-start: 0; /* removes the extra padding on the left side of links */
    }

    #copyright {
        color:#eeeeee; /* colors the footer text */
        font-size: 0.951vw; /* the font size of the copyright text is '13' */
        text-align: center; /* centers the  */
    }
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, it is little more than a suggestion. If you need more information, please ask in the comments. Otherwise please show the OP *how* to use these to solve the problem so that your answer is helpful.

Comment: I appreciate any help I can get. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: @LAF_OUT_LOUD well my first suggestion is not to start worrying about viewport units just yet! The problem is actually simpler than that. You are using absolute positioning for your main layout and you'll never get an effective responsive design using absolute positioning. Its quite easy to fix really, but seeing as no one else answered and I'm guessing you are still learning, I've added an answer to show you want to do!

Comment: @FluffyKitten Not worrying about Viewport Units right now is not correct because making a website responsive is one of the most important thing and post owner should learn that as soon as possible. Your answer is also correct and maybe better than me and I really appreciate your suggestion but downvoting someones answer could also down their moral, you should understand that and help new contributors. Downvoting someone else's answer to bring your answer to top  for getting it accecpted and more upvotes is unethical and if you get upvotes by that then your thousands of reputation is waste.

Comment: @LAF_OUT_LOUD checkout the other answer on your post it will solve your issue. And if you have any other issue let me know.

Comment: I didn't downvote your for using viewport units, as I said I didn't feel it has enough details to help the OP who seems to still be learning (its kinda throwing them in at the deep end :) ) I could have not commented at all so you wouldn't even know it was me, but I was trying to help by pointing out how to improve it, and I waited to give you time to do that. If you added more info, I'd have upvoted it (its still not too late btw). Downvoting is just part of how SO works - its not something to be demoralised over, it happens everyone. And I'm here 10 long years so 6k is not that impressive :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten for a 16 year old who only loves to code and coding only makes him happy 6k is a lot and I didn't wanted to write all that but the day has been so bad for me and seeing two downvotes demoralised me and I have been downvoted a couple of times before but that time my day was not that bad  and thanks for commenting because other downvoters never replied on what I did wrong. I have edited the answer and if there is some mistake let me know I will definitely solve it. And I am really sorry for being so rude (which I am not but I don't know how and why I said it :( ). Sorry :(

Comment: I understand. We're good :) Your answer looks good on larger screens but on small screens the header & footer cover the main container. Working with viewport units is tricky :) Take another look if you like, but I upvoted you for making the effort, that cancels out the other downvote too. For future answers, think about how it can help *other* users too, explanations help give a better answer. Don't fret the downvotes, it doesn't feel good but its only the internet :) You've a lot of rep for 15 days, so keep it up! These comments could be deleted for being chatty, so I'll leave it there :) :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thanks for your suggestion and upvoting my answer, For all my future answers I will always explain what have I done and do a bit more research before answering. And Thanks for making me understand to not worry about downvotes and how to properly write answer. And sorry for late reply because I was a bit busy with school work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `position:absolute` for *all* your main blocks! I'm guessing this is student work, so it would be worthwhile to read the links I've added in the explanation below.

**What is happening:**
[Absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) takes the elements out of the flow so they work independently of the rest of the page, so you have to use CSS to specify *exactly* where you want each one to appear. When one div grows, it will overlap with the next one because will still appear in the exact position you told in in the CSS.

**How to fix it:** Just use the default [normal flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout)! In the snippet below I've made the following changes:

1. Removed all CSS related to the absolute positioning, to restore normal flow
2. Added `display:flex` to your main blocks to prevent the [collapsing margin problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257018/how-to-disable-margin-collapse-between-sibling-elements)

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#nav, #main, #footer {
  display:flex;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #393e46;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

#nav-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 200px;
}

#rowA {
  background-color: red;
}

.nav-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#rowB {
  background-color: green;
}

#nav-logo {
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

#rowC {
  background-color: pink;
}

.nav-menu {
  float: right;
}


#main {
  background-color: orange;
}

#main-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #222831;
}

#footer-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.footer-row {
  padding-inline-start: 0px;
}

#copyright {
  color: #eeeeee;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <div id="nav-container">

    <!-- nav-row-1 -->
    <div id="rowA">
      <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="">Sign Up</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="">Log In</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- nav-row-1 -->
    <div id="rowB">
      <h3 id="nav-logo">DICTIONARY</h3>
    </div>

    <!-- nav-row-1 -->
    <div id="rowC">
      <form action="" method="get">
        <input id="nav-search-bar" type="search" placeholder="Search">
      </form>
    </div>


  </div>
</nav>


<!-- main section -->
<main id="main">
  <div id="main-container">

    <!-- header -->
    <div id="btd-masthead">
      <h2>Browse the Dictionary</h2>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <!-- btd links -->
    <div id="btd-links">

      <div id="btd-links-1">
        <a href="a.html">a</a>
        <a href="b.html">b</a>
        <a href="c.html">c</a>
        <a href="d.html">d</a>
        <a href="e.html">e</a>
        <a href="f.html">f</a>
        <a href="g.html">g</a>
        <a href="h.html">h</a>
        <a href="i.html">i</a>
        <a href="j.html">j</a>
        <a href="k.html">k</a>
        <a href="l.html">l</a>
        <a href="m.html">m</a>
        <a href="n.html">n</a>
        <a href="o.html">o</a>
        <a href="p.html">p</a>
        <a href="q.html">q</a>
        <a href="r.html">r</a>
        <a href="s.html">s</a>
        <a href="t.html">t</a>
        <a href="u.html">u</a>
        <a href="v.html">v</a>
        <a href="w.html">w</a>
        <a href="x.html">x</a>
        <a href="y.html">y</a>
        <a href="z.html">z</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div>

    </div>

    <!-- terms list row -->
    <div id="terms-container">

      <!-- column 1 -->
      <div class="terms-col">

        <a href="">Abare</a>
        <a href="../terms/a/adaptation.html">Adaptation</a>
        <a href="../terms/a/air_dash.html">Air Dash</a>
        <a href="">Air Throw</a>
        <a href="../terms/a/air_to_air.html">Air-to-Air</a>
        <a href="../terms/a/anti_air.html">Anti-Air</a>
        <a href="../terms/a/armor.html">Armor</a>
        <a href="">Assist</a>
        <a href="../terms/a/auto_correct.html">Auto Correct</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<!-- the footer stays the same on every page -->
<footer id="footer">
  <div id="footer-container">

    <!-- row 1 -->
    <ul class="footer-row">
      <li>
        <a href="a.html" style="text-transform: none;">Browse the Dictionary:</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="a.html">a</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="b.html">b</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="c.html">c</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="d.html">d</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="e.html">e</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="f.html">f</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="g.html">g</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="h.html">h</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="i.html">i</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="j.html">j</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="k.html">k</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="l.html">l</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="m.html">m</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="n.html">n</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="o.html">o</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="p.html">p</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="q.html">q</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="r.html">r</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="s.html">s</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="t.html">t</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="u.html">u</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="v.html">v</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="w.html">w</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="x.html">x</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="y.html">y</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="z.html">z</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- row 2 -->
    <ul class="footer-row">
      <li>
        <a href="../../index.html">home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="../about_us.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="../contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="../disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- row 3 -->
    <div class="footer-row">
      <p id="copyright">&copy; 2020 copyright</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Absolute positioning can be useful for the occasional element that needs to work independently of the rest of the page, but there is rarely (if ever) a need to use it for the main layout, especially in responsive design.

Comment: THANK YOU. I did what you suggested and it worked like a charm.